# SpringBoot user lacks privilege or object not found HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb

I've created an app with views for 3 entites bank client and credit using Spring Boot and Vaadin. Credit entity is similar to client.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS_TABLE")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private Long phone;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PASSPORT")
    private Long passport;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Bank.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id")
    private Bank bankMapped;
//getters and setters, toString
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANKS_TABLE")
public class Bank {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bankMapped", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Client.class)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Client> clientList = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bankMapped", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Credit.class)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Credit> creditList = new LinkedList<>();
//getters and setters
```

Next thing I did is adding HSQLDB via `application.propeties`. Heres the file:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
# Ensure application is run in Vaadin 14/npm mode
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:HSQLDB/DataBase
spring.datasource.username=SA
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

It did create a database [DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nVVC.png). But now whenever i try to open any view in my app the next exception os thrown.

```
2021-02-20 12:26:01.873 ERROR 12404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : user lacks privilege or object not found: BANK in statement [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]
2021-02-20 12:26:01.899 ERROR 12404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.v.flow.router.InternalServerError      : There was an exception while trying to navigate to 'clients'

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:135) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:134) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:518) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:498) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:230) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.lambda$initializeUI$caa7783a$1(Router.java:90) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.NavigationRpcHandler.handle(NavigationRpcHandler.java:66) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:409) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:317) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1547) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.services.BankService.findAll(BankService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView.<init>(ClientListView.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BANK in statement [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    ... 135 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BANK
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 141 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you try to add password to your sa user?

Comment: Yes i did, but it didnt fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of this problem was in wrong types of entity fields. Dont make a mistake like me using Double and Long classes.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the stack trace is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.ClientListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

What happens if you run this against your database outside of spring (i.e. directly from a db client)?

```
select bank0_.id as id1_0_, bank0_.Name as name2_0_ from BANK bank0_
```

It looks strange to see the `id` field as all lowercase, the `Name` field with the first letter as uppercase and the table `BANK` as all uppercase.

The `@Column(name = "...")` annotation doesn't look like it's working, with the `@Table(name = "...")` because if that were the case the query would be

```
select bank0_.ID as id1_0_, bank0_.NAME as name2_0_ from BANKS_TABLE bank0_
```

If you connect directly to the database you can check to see what the table is actually called, if it exists, and that will give you an indication of where the problem is. From the exception it looks like either

- The hibernate table and column name mappings are not working correctly: the query in the exception is on a `BANKS` table but the java class is for a `BANKS_TABLE` table.
- There is no `BANKS` table in the database: the query looks for a table called `BANKS` and doesn't find it.
- There is a table and it is not available for the database user the app uses to connect.

To troubleshoot, what is the name of the table supposed to be according to your database and does that table actually exist for the user?

Comment: I tried removing all column annotations. Unfortunately it didnt fix the problem. I tried changing the spring.jpa.hibernate property to update ( i removed the property initialization property too) and now this happens when starting the app: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table clients_table (id binary(255) generated by default as identity (start with 1), email varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, passport bigint, phone bigint, bank_id binary(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement.

Comment: With the column and table annotations gone, did anything in the query change?

Comment: All fields are now lower case

Comment: Table name is in lower case too. I changed the table annotation accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the exception is still thrown whenever i try to open an entity view.

Comment: Verify the name of your table and the name of the columns in the database. Can you also update the question with the actual query method you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't quite understand what you are asking. Im am using Maven to inject hsqldb.jar and i thought that needed queries are generated automatically.

Comment: If you are using magic query methods on a jpa repository or something similar then yes, the queries are generated automatically. How they are generated depends on how you map them with the annotations on your entity. If the mapping does not coincide with what is actually in the database they will not work. Try to run the generated query from the first line of the stack trace directly in your database. Connect to it with a client and see what's in there.

Comment: I tried running this query in this Database through HSQL Database Manager and i get SQL Error : user lacks privilege or object not found: BANK / Error Code: -5501 / State: 42501. It seems like the tables do not exist when they are called.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean when I say there is a mapping problem. The table `BANK` doesn't exist (or the user can't see it). Since your model defines it with the name 'BANK_TABLE', try querying with that table name and see if that table is there. If yes, you have a hibernate configuration problem. If no, you have a database problem.

Comment: Seems like its a database problem, because even after changing the table name in query to the same as in the entiry annotation the error is still the same.

Comment: I updated the answer in a way that I think is more clear and summarizes the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Now i know where the problem is.